# How to repartition dataframe after filter? pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
df = df.where(df.count>5)
```

Df before filter had 500M rows and after filter it has 10M rows. 
I understood that repartition can improve performance in this case because the data size changed dramatically and partitions number stay the same.
My question is how to choose the column to make repartition with?
I have key column that is unique between all the values and category column that is not distinct
Should I make `df.repartition("key")` ? (key have 10M distinct values out of 10M)
Should i make `df.repartition("category")` ? (Category have 200k distinct values out of 10M)

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to achieve with the partitioned Dataframe. Simply calling `repartition` will first slow down your performance as it requires a full shuffle. What are you planning to do with the partitioned daza? Also, how many Executors and Cores do you have available?

Comment: @mike I have a lot of logic after this filter on this df(joins, aggregations and more).
I have 30 executors with 5 cores each

Comment: @mike But what is the meaning of repartition column that have 10M values? I guess that it won't split the data to 10M partitions and will consider the size of the data too. isn't it?

Comment: In my common sense the repartition should be done on the column with the most distinct values in order to get the best result. Do I miss something? @mike

Comment: In my experience the partitioning of the data should happen based on the actual business logic. You want to avoid creating skewed data that will slow down your joins, aggregations etc. Without knowing what exactly you are doing with the data, there is (in my knowledge) no way of telling you how to partition the data. There is no general silver bullet on how to partition your data that will solve all potential problems. It is a case-by-case decision.

Comment: @mike What are the downsides I can have if I repartition by the key column?
I understand that I have shuffle and overhead by doing it but isn't it worth it if I have a lot of logic after that?
I have a lot of logic that depends on this df - if I have too much partitions it will hurt my performance, isn't it?